# Portable generic shared library setup with Qt event loop

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, qt5, platform-independent

We are trying to write a portable shared library that makes use of some Qt classes for convenience (mainly `QTimer` and `QTcpSocket`); no GUI stuff, though. The according signal/slot connections appear to require some Qt event loop, so we "prime" a `QCoreApplication` as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42303348/2531146). Accordingly, we set up a worker object that does the heavy lifting and move it to a `QThread`.

The problem we run into now is that the queued connections between the `QThread`'s owner object (within the main thread) and the worker object within the `QThread` seem to never get handled on Linux systems, at least as long as the program that implements our library does not provide any further Qt event loop of its own in the main thread. This is not very helpful, since the data passed from the worker to the main thread should be passed further using some callback functions, which now never get called, though.

My question is thus: is there a way to get an event loop to work in the library main thread without locking it or the host program up (which seems to be the case when just putting a `QCoreApplication::exec()` or similar there)? Or will we have to set up a different inter-thread communication scheme (independent from Qt) in order to deal with these data transfers?

Since we do not know if the host software is going to run on a `QApplication` or not, ideally I'd also have a check for that before setting up a main thread event loop. Is a simple `if(qApp != nullptr)` enough for that?

P.S.: A few things I tried but which did not work for me, either:

- Settings up a `QEventLoop` in a `std::thread` launched from the main thread (probably not working because still not in the main thread)
- Setting up a `QEventLoop` in the main thread class and triggering its `processEvents()` function periodically using a `QTimer` (probably not working due to the missing event loop for the `QTimer::timeout` signal in the main function)
- Starting the `QCoreApplication` in a `std::thread` (gives a run-time warning on Windows that QCoreApplication should be started in the main thread)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but just a friendly advice: If you're not using Qt GUI, don't use Qt stuff. Qt is a monster and including the whole Qt base engine just for QTimer and QTcpSocket is a tremendous overkill. You're better off using boost for such things. More portable, simpler and license friendly.

Comment: I get your point and do consider re-writing accordingly - however, we have quite some experience with Qt, and little to none with Boost. Using what you know well when starting a new project seems more efficient on first sight, but given that we never used Qt in a shared library setting before, we could of course not really foresee these troubles the whole event handling system would bring with itself.

Comment: Regarding your third try: A warning is not an error. Did it work with the core app on a seperate thread? if yes, thats a valid solution, as the warning is only there because having the core app on any different thread prevents it from catching some system events, making for example creating a gui impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt parlance, a callback is called `Qt::DirectConnection`. But of course those callbacks will run on your worker thread. But that’d be the case with any other library that uses callbacks, so Qt is not a problem here, and neither is your code: the basic idea has this property.

If the host application is not using an event loop (any event loop, not necessarily Qt’s), then there’s nothing you can do other than polling – see below.

If the host application runs an X11 event loop, then you need to ensure that your copy of Qt is using the same underlying event loop as the host application. Usually, this would be the glib’s event loop, and then it should work automagically. Otherwise, you’ll need to pass to the user the file descriptor of the synchronization primitive used by Qt’s event loop, and the user will need to integrate it into their event loop. You’ll face the same problem whether you use Qt or not: rolling your own communication method won’t fix it, since you still need a waitable primitive that will interoperate with whatever event loop the user is using.

The user can of course poll for callbacks whenever they feel like it: expose a `mainPoll()` method that forwards to `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`.

Comment: We're already offering the option to poll for data to the implementing application. The intention of the callback structure is to allow users to register functions so that they can get notified whenever new data is available (i.e. asynchronously), and not having to go the polling route if not desired. But seeing your explanation I have little hope of getting that part to work now :/

Comment: There’s no magic to it: if you know nothing about the client’s event loop, then it won’t happen automatically. You can give your client a file descriptor they can wait on, and then issue your `poll` only when the descriptor is ready and thus there are callbacks to be processed. On Linux, the file descriptors are the equivalent of waitable object handles on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Despite accepting another answer (which I deem more correct), I'd still like to mention a workaround that worked surprisingly well: We actually managed to get around the event loop/thread problems on most systems by connecting the worker thread signals with lambda functions in constructor of the class that sets up the worker.

Now, I doubt that this behaviour is properly thread-safe, and having relatively lengthy lambda functions declared in `connect` function calls is certainly not good style. But in case anyone else ends up struggling with this issue, this may be a short-term solution or (temporary) workaround.